# SceneBuilder node not selectable

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, fxml, scenebuilder

In my JavaFX app some nodes show in the preview but are not selectable and do not show in the hierarchy. SceneBuilder untargetable example:

[image: SceneBuilder untargetable example]

In this example the "First Name" column is not targetable and does not show in the hierarchy even though it has the same code as the "Last Name" column.
Same thing with the "New..." and "Edit..." button.

My SceneBuilder version is 8.3.0.
I'm using eclipse and I'm editing the fxml through FXGraph if I have to do that manually.

FXML:

```
<AnchorPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="de.is2.address.view.PersonOverviewController" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="600.0">

<children>
    <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.29797979797979796" layoutX="130.0" layoutY="70.0" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0"> 
        <items>
            <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0"> 
                <children>
                    <TableView fx:id="personTable" layoutX="-25.0" layoutY="-21.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0"> 
                        <columns>
                            <TableColumn fx:id="firstNameColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="First Name"/> 
                        </columns>
                        <columns>
                            <TableColumn fx:id="lastNameColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Last Name"/> 
                        </columns>
                        <columnResizePolicy><TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" /></columnResizePolicy>
                    </TableView>
                </children>
            </AnchorPane>
            <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0"> 
                <children>
                    <Label layoutX="54.0" layoutY="37.0" text="Person Details" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="5.0"/> 
                    <GridPane layoutX="67.0" layoutY="78.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="30.0"> 
                        <columnConstraints>
                            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0"/> 
                        </columnConstraints>
                        <columnConstraints>
                            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0"/> 
                        </columnConstraints>
                        <rowConstraints>
                            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/> 
                        </rowConstraints>
                        <rowConstraints>
                            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/> 
                        </rowConstraints>
                        <rowConstraints>
                            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/> 
                        </rowConstraints>
                        <rowConstraints>
                            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/> 
                        </rowConstraints>
                        <rowConstraints>
                            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/> 
                        </rowConstraints>
                        <rowConstraints>
                            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/> 
                        </rowConstraints>
                        <children>
                            <Label text="First Name"/> 
                            <Label text="Last Name" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/> 
                            <Label text="Street" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/> 
                            <Label text="City" GridPane.rowIndex="3"/> 
                            <Label text="Postal Code" GridPane.rowIndex="4"/> 
                            <Label text="Birthday" GridPane.rowIndex="5"/> 
                            <Label fx:id="firstNameLabel" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1"/> 
                            <Label fx:id="lastNameLabel" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/> 
                            <Label fx:id="streetLabel" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/> 
                            <Label fx:id="cityLabel" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3"/> 
                            <Label fx:id="postalCodeLabel" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4"/> 
                            <Label fx:id="birthdayLabel" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="5"/> 
                        </children>
                    </GridPane>
                    <ButtonBar layoutX="203.0" layoutY="244.0" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="265.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="10.0"> 
                        <buttons>
                            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="New..."/> 
                        </buttons>
                        <buttons>
                            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit..."/> 
                        </buttons>
                        <buttons>
                            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleDeletePerson" text="Delete"/> 
                        </buttons>
                    </ButtonBar>
                </children>
            </AnchorPane>
        </items>
    </SplitPane>
</children>
```

Comment: Which SceneBuilder version are you using? The GridPane shows 61 rows and 13 columns? Do you actually have all of them? Do you see the GridPane when you select it?

Comment: You have a column called 'LastName' but no column called 'First Name'. Is the column 'LastName' selectable?

Comment: @JoséPereda My SceneBuilder version is 8.3.0. 
The 61 rows and 13 columns were weird unused code, I'm not sure where they came from, maybe that I'm also using FXGraph caused a weird interaction there.
Otherwise the gridpane is working fine.

Comment: @Kerry The "Last Name" column is working as inteded and is selectable.

Comment: Can you try removing or cleaning that code? I did try your layout with a SplitPane and a TableView from the scratch, and I couldn't reproduce your issue.

Comment: "From the scratch" meaning directly in SceneBuilder, without using FXGraph. If FXGraph caused that weird GridPane, maybe it did something over the TableView too. Can you post the FXML file (at least the part related to the TableView)?

Comment: Are there any errors or warnings produced by Scene Builder? Are there any uncaught exceptions (should be printed to terminal when running from console/terminal window). This sounds like either a malformed FXML or a bug in Scene Builder (or possibly both).

Comment: Are you using the Gluon Scene Builder? http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/ - I've found it to be very useful.

Comment: I might be missing something here but in the "Hierarchy" view on the left, I do not see a 'TableCoumn' object (named 'first Name") nor do I see two further buttons 'New...' and 'Edit..' there... which I imagine means that the are not selectable. I don't know why the two buttons are displayed in the preview though. Perhaps a bug in 8.3.0? Can you post the FXML?

Comment: I posted the FXML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At several places in your FXML, you are repeatedly defining the contents of the same tags like this (snippet):

```
<columns>
   <TableColumn fx:id="firstNameColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="First Name"/> 
</columns>
<columns> <!-- repetition!! -->  
   <TableColumn fx:id="lastNameColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Last Name"/> 
</columns>
```

This is incorrect - you should open the tag once, then specify all the children, then close it once. You are doing it correctly for the GridPane's children, for example:

```
<GridPane layoutX="67.0" layoutY="78.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="30.0"> 
    <children>
        <Label text="First Name"/> 
        <Label text="Last Name" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/> 
        <Label text="Street" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/> 
        ...
    </children>
</GridPane>
```

From my experience, JavaFx itself accepts (as in, displays as expected) some very interesting FXML constructs, but SceneBuilder tends to be more conservative and only accepts the typical constructs. This is probably why the preview looks fine, but the hierarchy is incomplete. If you edit your FXML by hand, take a look first at the way SceneBuilder would create the same structures - that's the way it expects them to be.

If you correct the nesting everywhere, the resulting FXML is:

```
<AnchorPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="de.is2.address.view.PersonOverviewController"
    prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="600.0">

    <children>
        <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.29797979797979796" layoutX="130.0" layoutY="70.0" prefHeight="300.0"
            prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0"
            AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
            <items>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                    <children>
                        <TableView fx:id="personTable" layoutX="-25.0" layoutY="-21.0" prefHeight="200.0"
                            prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0"
                            AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                            <columns>
                                <TableColumn fx:id="firstNameColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="First Name" />
                                <TableColumn fx:id="lastNameColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Last Name" />
                            </columns>
                            <columnResizePolicy>
                                <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
                            </columnResizePolicy>
                        </TableView>
                    </children>
                </AnchorPane>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                    <children>
                        <Label layoutX="54.0" layoutY="37.0" text="Person Details" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0"
                            AnchorPane.topAnchor="5.0" />
                        <GridPane layoutX="67.0" layoutY="78.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0"
                            AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="30.0">
                            <columnConstraints>
                                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                            </columnConstraints>
                            <rowConstraints>
                                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                            </rowConstraints>
                            <children>
                                <Label text="First Name" />
                                <Label text="Last Name" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                                <Label text="Street" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                                <Label text="City" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                                <Label text="Postal Code" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
                                <Label text="Birthday" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
                                <Label fx:id="firstNameLabel" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                                <Label fx:id="lastNameLabel" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1"
                                    GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                                <Label fx:id="streetLabel" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1"
                                    GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                                <Label fx:id="cityLabel" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                                <Label fx:id="postalCodeLabel" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1"
                                    GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
                                <Label fx:id="birthdayLabel" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1"
                                    GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
                            </children>
                        </GridPane>
                        <ButtonBar layoutX="203.0" layoutY="244.0" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="265.0"
                            AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="10.0">
                            <buttons>
                                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="New..." />
                                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit..." />
                                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleDeletePerson" text="Delete" />
                            </buttons>
                        </ButtonBar>
                    </children>
                </AnchorPane>
            </items>
        </SplitPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

This gives me the desired result in SceneBuilder 8.4.1: All table columns and all buttons in the ButtonBar are displayed and selectable in the hierarchy.